# Funcionalidade Calculadora de Bhaskara em PYTHON

Tags: python, matemática, shortcode

Olá, ainda sou estudante e gostaria de saber se algum modo de fazer mais compacta está calculadora de Bhaskara que eu fiz. Gostaria de uma que mostrasse todos os passos como ela faz.

```
print('BHASKARA SOLVER')
print('Ax² + Bx + C = 0')
while True:
    print('Digite um número')
    a1 = input('Digite o A:')
    try:
        a1 = float(a1)
    except ValueError:
        print("Não é número, Digite somente números.")
    if type(a1) == float:
        break
while True:
    print('Digite um número')
    b1 = input('Digite o B:')
    try:
        b1 = float(b1)
    except ValueError:
        print("Não é número, Digite somente números.")
    if type(b1) == float:
        break
while True:
    print('Digite um número')
    c1 = input('Digite o C:')
    try:
        c1 = float(c1)
    except ValueError:
        print("Não é número, Digite somente números.")
    if type(c1) == float:
        break
a = float(a1)
b = float(b1)
c = float(c1)
delta = b**2 - 4*a*c
raiz = delta ** (1/2)
x1 = (-b+raiz)/(2*a)
x2 = (-b-raiz)/(2*a)
if delta < 0:
    exit('Delta negativo, Bhaskara sem solução')
if x1 == x2:
    exit(f'X1 e X2 são iguais. Resultado X = {x1}')
if x1 != x2:
    exit(f'X1= {x1} X2= {x2}')
```

Comment: "mostrasse todos os passos como ela faz" - como assim ?

Comment: Pelo que entendi, uma que mostre o passo a passo da solução. Algo similar ao que pode ser obtido no [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/pro-features/step-by-step-solutions/)

Comment: Recomendo ler [este artigo em inglês](https://blog.socratic.org/stepping-into-math-open-sourcing-our-step-by-step-solver-9b5da066ae36) no Medium. Em que cogitam utilizar o SymPy, mas acabam utilizando o math.js para criar uma biblioteca de passo a passo para o aplicativo Math Steps.

Comment: Obrigado a todos pelas respostas, darei uma lida no que mandaram!!